# Distributing/hosting application on linux machine

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi so previously I was hosting my application on windows and wrote a service that would check the RUNNING_PID file, if that process didn't exist launch a new shell and start the application again.

I currently distribute the application using the script: play clean update dist. So this creates my .jar files and my start script

But now I am trying to setup the system on linux (ubuntu but will change if easier). I was planning on writing a python script to do the same thing and making it a cron job to check it is running every 15minutes. The script would check the file pid, make sure that it is running and then start the service. This is working but when i launch a new subprocess for start: ./start & it prints out all the play output and waits for the process to close.

Is there a better way to create a watchdog type service for playframework?

Even when I try to run ./start & script from a shell it does not launch a new background thread.

Answer (score 1):

In case of crashing RUNNING_PID could remains in a system. Better to watch for port listener with `sudo netstat -lpn |grep :9000` or change last line of start script to something like `nohup java $* -cp $classpath play.core.server.NettyServer` dirname $0`> out.txt &` and watch for process writing to out.txt with `lsof | grep "out.txt"`

Comment: Yeah I think the port listener is a great idea thanks. Unfortunately though this problem still does not cause the script end. I want to start a process that does not block the original python script. But when launching the NettyServer command it locks the python script. If you type the above: nohup java $* -cp $classpath play.core.server.NettyServer dirname $0> out.txt & in a bash script it locks the current terminal screen. How do i get around this

Comment: I think, it's better to refer with Python-related docs on how to start a new thread. E.g. http://softwareramblings.com/2008/06/running-functions-as-threads-in-python.html